Can a shell opened via SSH "inherit"/use the same environment as a local shell? Non-interactive shell on MacOS can, "sometimes", not access Keychain
I use Pushbullet and a third party Python script that allows me to send "pushes" from the command line. This script uses MacOS "Keychain" to access passwords and tokens used for Pushbullet.
If I execute the script locally, something like
% pb push "SE demo"

in works fine and the "push" is sent as expected, but I need to send it using ssh from machine A to B:
% ssh B pb push "SE\ demo"

but when I do I get a traceback that the script can't access Keychain. I can work around that by first unlocking the Keychain:
% security -i unlock-keychain

but you have to do that everytime you want to send a push, which kind of defeats the purpose of the Keychain.
The key difference between a local shell and ssh is that ssh shells are non-interactive (if I open a local shell and su I get a non-login but interactive shell - in such a shell it still works to send these pushes/there are no issues with Keychain).
How can I, using ssh, access the environment of a local interactive shell so my script can access the Keychain?
Additional details.
What I am actually doing is running an AppleScript via SSH:
% ssh B osascript ~/scripts/myscript

At the end of this AppleScript I execute a shell script that sends this Pushbullet push
do shell script "pb push 'done'"

and it is this command that fails because it can't access the Keychain. If I execute the AppleScript locally on B, from the Script Editor or the command line, the do shell script-part works. OTOH, AppleScript reports that the environment it executes its do shell-script is non-interactive and non-login.

This does not look like it's related to shell type (which has little impact aside from reading .profile stuff) – I vaguely remember that it is a very MacOS-kernel-specific thing (Mach ports)...
